# Changing list in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, list, sockets

I have msg list and socket list and i want to change it between the 2 threads so one can change it and both can use the new one.
The code is the server of chat who more than 2 clients can connect and talk to each other
Here is the code:

```
import threading
import socket
import time
global Clients
global MsgQue
def inputmsg():
  while 1:
        try:
            Clients.append(server.accept())
        except socket.error:
            print("No new Socket")
        for cli in Clients:
            try:
                MsgQue.append(cli[0].recv(4096))
            except socket.error:
                print("Warning no input")
def outputmsg():
   for cli in Clients:
       if(MsgQue):
          cli[0].send(MsgQue[0])
          MsgQue.pop(0)

threads = []
server = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1212
server.bind((host,port))
server.setblocking(0)
server.listen(5)
Clients = []
MsgQue = []
threading._start_new_thread(inputmsg,())
threading._start_new_thread(outputmsg,())
while 1:
    if( 1 == 4):
        print ("WTF")
```

Comment: Don't use lists, use a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue)s.

Comment: Don't use `global` and don't use `_start_new_thread`. And don't use busy loops. Use a protocol for messages, use `select` to read from multiple sockets.